# Ingress faction change: How much warning is given to save items?

Tags: ingress

I've submitted for a faction change in Ingress, and there doesn't seem to be good information on this elsewhere.  Does the process give you enough warning to drop capsules of items to be picked up afterward, or does it force the faction change on you immediately when you open the app after the change has gone through?

Comment: I'm mainly thinking of sentimental keys collected over the last couple years playing that I'd rather not lose.  If I don't find an answer here, I'll come back and update this question with the answer once I learn the hard way.

Comment: I'd suggest giving the items you want to keep to a friend who is playing to keep until the change is over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change will happen immediately when Niantic approves your change request. Once you put in the request, assume that it could happen at any time.

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct and helped me save my items.  As an interesting note though:  everything inside my key lockers _survived the faction change!_  Unfortunately in my case it was mostly junk keys, but it could be useful information for other people.